# Is it idiomatic to say, 'someone's hand finds something'?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

If a guy's hand touches something, then he looks at what he just touched and now knows that thing is here, is it idiomatic to say, 'his hand found this stuff'?

Comment: I groped in the dark cupboard and my hand found something soft, cold, and wet. Oh God! What was it? Yes, it's fine.

Comment: Your hand can find something before you know what it is.

Comment: If it was soft, warm, and wet, that might be worse.

Comment: Yes, it's valid,. There are even tools such as stud *finders*, to locate wooden supports in walls. Also, a *finder's fee* can be paid to an intermediary, as one who finds a product for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder's_fee

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is fine.  You can find many examples of e.g. **His outstretched hand found..** in [literature](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his+outstretched+hand+found%22&sxsrf=ALiCzsZv29Il-NcSpozBXGvNEi_-6CiHvA:1671041286937&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEisDy2fn7AhWLNcAKHWhxAhEQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1440&bih=790&dpr=2).